# MySQL/EF 5: can't save m:n relation

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I use a MySQL DB (5.6) via Entity Framework 5 with .NET 4.5.

There is a relation between two tables as a m:n relation: tblLeft with a column leftId, tblRight with a column rightId and a table tblBetween with two columns leftId and rightId. The fields leftId and rightId are primary keys in their tables and the tblBetween has got foreign keys for both columns. All columns are defined as "Int(4) NOT NULL"

When I use the object models as follows:

InstanceOfLeft.Rights.Add(InstanceOfRights)

or

InstanceOfRight.Lefts.Add(InstanceOfLeft)

I get an exception. The most inner one says:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT
`tblBetween`.`rightId`, 
`tblBetween`.`t' at line 1

I have no idea what this means and how I may solve this. Can anybody help?

Best regards,
Torsten